# The cluster is going through a an upgrade which cannot be interrupted on servicefabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am getting some error that seems to not go away with service fabric:

```
C:\Users\pks>armclient put /subscriptions/8393a037-5d39-462d-a583-09915b4493df/resourcegroups/TestServiceFabric11/providers/Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters/pksservicefabric11?api-version=2016-03-01 @updatenodesga.json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "PendingClusterUpgradeCannotBeInterrupted",
    "message": "The cluster is going through a an upgrade which cannot be interrupted."
  }
}
```

from the resource properties the state has gone into some AutoScale mode, which i have no idea what means:

```
"provisioningState": "Failed",
"clusterId": "bfb52d19-238b-4046-8e35-ad95697c79b6",
"clusterCodeVersion": "5.0.135.9590",
"clusterState": "AutoScale",
```

If anything from the servicefabric team have a comment on what AutoScale means that would be nice? I have been able to update the resource before even with the promisioningstate failed, but the autoscale is something i havent seen before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have two questions here

1) When is the cluster state set to "AutoScale"? Cluster State is set to "AutoScale" when ever there is a change in reliability level. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-capacity/ for details on reliability levels.

2) Why did you get the error message  - "The cluster is going through a an upgrade which cannot be interrupted." ?

It looks like you deleted your cluster, else it would have been easier to pin point what exactly happened here, but here is what I think may have happened. Please do provide repro steps if my guess is incorrect.

As a part of the scale up , after adding VM instances- you changed the reliability level (Silver to Gold). This prompted the SF cluster to proceed to change the target replica set sizes of the system services and mark the cluster state as "AutoScale". This particular kind of configuration upgrade is also marked as "uninterruptible" by the system, since it impacts the system services. Before this upgrade had finished, you tried to scale down the cluster by changing the reliability level (from Gold to Silver), which prompted the system to block it and raising the error message.

Comment: Ye sorry about deleting it, i just decided to redeploy as I could not figure it out :)  If I can reproduce it I will send the information to you guys. (it was not my intention to change reliability level, but not unthinkable that could be the case, now i know what to look for next time).

Comment: My cluster is also having "The cluster is going through a an upgrade which can not be interrupted" after swapping a secondary certificate to primary certificate using the portal interface. It seems to be stuck as it is in this state for like 20 hours now.

Comment: Did you deploy the secondary cert via a VMSS Model change, prior to coming and defining the secondary cert on the portal ? if not, it could be that the Service Fabric (SF) runtime is not finding the secondary cert locally on the VM to swap out. SF does not deploy certs, VMSS/Key vault agent in the VM does..